# Which reviews are rarer than others?

Tags: discussion, review, statistics

Which reviews are rarer than others?

I think that late answers should be the rarest but I want a order of rarity of them.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

At the time of writing, the global number of reviews done was:

1. Close: 398,338
2. Suggested Edits: 262,766
3. First Posts: 210,381
4. Low Quality: 205,281
5. Reopen: 69,808
6. Late Answer: 23,339

Personally, I was a bit surprised that First Post is that high in the list. 
Subjectively, I would have thought it below Low Quality and closer to Reopen.

It should be noted that the criteria for reviewing sometimes change, which can change the current number of reviews relative to the global number.

[image: global number of reviews]

Comment: You forgot suggested edits.

Comment: Indeed. I added the information

Comment: One factor is that the privilege to review First Posts and Late Answers [is given at $500$ reputation points](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/access-review-queues), much earlier than other queues.  So there are more "eyeballs" on these items.

Comment: I added a pie chart :) Hope you don't mind.

Comment: How come you know these values ? :) thanks

Comment: @ritwiksinha go [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/review) and click on "recent review" in the queue you're interested in. You'll find the total number of reviews and the reviewer ranking.