# How many of the steward medals are for reviewing each type of review?

Tags: discussion, review, badges, statistics

How many of the steward medals are for reviewing each type of review -- Close Votes, Low Quality posts, and so on?

I want to check which one is rarer. I need this information where can I filter then by review type.

Comment: Announcing "I want to do whatever gets me the rarer badges" is not a particularly good conduct on this website. Sure, it's not disallowed or discouraged in any public way. But I can attest that when I see people whose actions are stated as badge-motivated, I usually begin by assuming that their actions are not as well-intended as other people's actions. So if there is any doubt, I will probably err to the side of "they are doing this solely to get badges, and this is inappropriate". I doubt that I am the only person to see things like that, too.

Comment: (To extend the above comment, this would also mean that I will be faster to downvote and slower to upvote their posts (although I will not do either without a good reason), because I don't like the idea of people who game badges to have privileges to affect the website. (I know, this is a losing battle, uphill on a very steep slope. Nevertheless, I have some hopes the site won't be completely tarnished by gaming badges.))

Comment: @Asaf Karagila I just asked how many people have every badge.I don't want to earn them.

Comment: So you are asking "How many of the steward medals was awarded for reviewing every review?" Go to the [review](http://math.stackexchange.com/review) page and click "recent reviews" for each reviews task. You can sort of see the stat there.

Comment: In the list of badges the type is specified. I am tired.  So now you do the count on http://math.stackexchange.com/help/badges/228/steward and post a self-answer! :-)

Comment: @quid Isn't any way to filter it.Counting way is boaring.

Comment: @TahaAkbari Then simply download the few pages with badges from quid's link and user [grep](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grep) or some similar tool to extract lines containing the string "First Posts" (and similarly for other queues). Any decent editor can show you number of lines in a text file.

Comment: "I need this information". "Gathering it is boring". And your time is more valuable than someone else's because...?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The list of people recently awarded the Steward badge is [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/badges/228/steward). I used this list and some quick-and-dirty use of ctrl-F to count the number of Steward badges of each type. Here are the results.

*(Note: I include "breakdown by page" which is the number of results on each page; there are 6 pages of badges in the above link. "In the past year" actually means from pages 1 and 2, which is between September 7 2015 and today, August 11 2016.)*

#### Steward badges awarded on mathSE

Total number of Steward badges awarded: **343**

- **141** Close Votes; **48** in the past year. (Breakdown by page: 22 + 26 + 24 + 30 + 27 + 12)
- **61** Low Quality Posts; **29** in the past year. (Breakdown by page: 14 + 15 + 12 + 10 + 8 + 2)
- **62** First Posts; **17** in the past year. (Breakdown by page: 10 + 7 + 12 + 10 + 12 + 11)
- **53** Suggested Edits; **14** in the past year. (Breakdown by page: 8 + 6 + 7 + 6 + 9 + 17)
- **22** Reopen Votes; **9** in the past year. (Breakdown by page: 5 + 4 + 5 + 4 + 3 + 1)
- **4** Late Answers; **3** in the past year. (Breakdown by page: 1 + 2 + 0 + 0 + 1 + 0)

[image]

[image]

The data confirms my experience that Close Votes are the easiest to accumulate a lot of reviews of, especially recently; low quality posts are next, then first posts, then edits, then reopen votes, and finally late answers. Only a select few have managed to get the Late Answers Steward badge.

[This question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24790/which-reviews-are-rarer-than-others?cb=1) contains information about the total number of reviews ever completed of each type, which may also be relevant to you.

**IMPORTANT:** Review carefully. Take a serious look at each post, vote appropriately and in accordance with site norms, and skip reviews you don't know what to do with. **Do not just speed through the reviews quickly, or you will get banned from reviewing. Do not abuse the review process just to get a badge.** Good luck.

Comment: This statistics is interesting, because suggested edit reviews count even when not done from the review page directly (unlike close votes and the like). One would have expected them to be slightly easier to obtain, then.